# PHP - Email is not sending

Tags: php, email

There are two steps first the email i sent to the person who wants the newsletter and the second email needs to be sent to info@dirtytrend.com. The problem is that the email is sent in the first step but the email in the second step is never getting through but the code seems to carry on without any errors.

The code is below

```
<?php


$name = $_POST["nameofperson"];
$to = $_POST["emailofperson"];
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi " . $name . ",<br><br>Thank you for subscribing?\n\nWe have logged your email to process your newsletter and you will recieve an email from us confirming your subscription.";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {



    $body2 = "Name: " . $name . "\n";
    $body2 .= "Email: " . $to;
    if(mail("info@dirtytrend.com", "Subscription Request", $body2)){

        header("Location: http://www.dirtytrend.com/events.html");
    }
    else{

    }

 } else {
    echo "ERROR: Email not sent please contact the system administrator";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: because you forgot headers in the second `mail`?

Comment: may be you are receiving this email as spam. Please check it once.

Answer (score 0):

In the second mail() you have only 3 parameters and you're missing the 4th one with the headers so maybe it is recognized as spam?